# Regular Expressions - How to match any 4 letter word on one list with any 4 letter word on another ignoring special characters? Just a-z

Tags: sql-server, regex

Regular Expressions - How to match any **3 letter word or more** on one list with any **3 letter word or more** on another ignoring special characters? Just a-z, replaces special characters with spaces.

What I'm using in my SQL query is $[a-z] but it has limitations where if the base list has ()/.,&

For example,

```
List A:
Bank of America
BofA
Bank of America Riverside
Bank of America Inc.
Bank and America
BankOfAmerica
International Business Machine

List B:
Bank of America (BofA)
IBM
```

I'd like for all **Bank of America** to match.

**So result:**

```
Bank of America (BofA) = Bank of America 
Bank of America (BofA) = BofA 
Bank of America (BofA) = Bank of America Riverside 
Bank of America (BofA) = Bank of America Inc.
Bank of America (BofA) = Bank and America
Bank of America (BofA) = BankOfAmerica
```

Here's what my SQL query looks like so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ListA, ListB
FROM ListData
WHERE ((ListA  LIKE '%[^a-z]' + ListB +'[^a-z]%') OR 
(ListA  LIKE ListB +'[^a-z]%') OR
(ListA  LIKE '%[^a-z]' + ListB)
OR ListA LIKE ListB)
ORDER BY ListB
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: From ListaData database, I'm just using the above SQL code as an example, the real code has a cross join from 2 databases. If you'd like to see that, let me know.

Comment: No, I meant which database engine; MySQL,SQL Server, Posrgres, Oracle, etc?

Comment: SQL Server using Management Studio

Comment: I'm not sure your requirements are clear enough. Are you saying you want to extract all 3-grams from the strings and see if there is at least one 3-gram match between the 2 strings?

Comment: Yes, I believe you're correct, I'd like it to ignore (Inc, Corp, Incorporated, Corporation) though.

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE to extract all the 3-grams. You can use replace to exclude the strings you don't want to include. To that end, and to replace special characters, you may want to create a UDF to do that.

Comment: By the way, your sample results don't match what you say you want. Given what you said you want, then the `U.S. Bank` should match all the `Bank of America` values and vice versa. Anything with the word bank should match everything else that has the word bank.

Comment: You're right, it was a bonus, I should simplify the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to extract all the 3-grams for comparison. Example below. I wouldn't use a preprocessing CTE though, that was just for ease, I would create a UDF to extract stuff you don't want.

```
declare @t1 table (field1 varchar(50));
declare @t2 table (field2 varchar(50));

insert into @t1 values 
    ('Bank of America'),
    ('BofA'),
    ('Bank of America Riverside'),
    ('Bank of America Inc.'),
    ('Bank and America'),
    ('BankOfAmerica'),
    ('International Business Machine')
;

insert into @t2 values 
    ('Bank of America (BofA)'),
    ('IBM')
;

WITH preprocessCTE1 AS (
    SELECT 
        field1,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field1, 'Inc.', ''), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '.', ' '), '.', ' ') AS processedfield1
    FROM @t1
),

preprocessCTE2 AS (
    SELECT 
        field2,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field2, 'Inc.', ''), '(', ' '), ')', ' '), '.', ' '), '.', ' ') AS processedfield2
    FROM @t2
),

recurse1 AS (
    SELECT 
        field1,
        processedfield1,
        1 AS Position,
        SUBSTRING(processedfield1, 1, 3) AS Trigram
    FROM preprocessCTE1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        field1,
        processedfield1,
        Position + 1 AS Position,
        SUBSTRING(processedfield1, Position + 1, 3) AS Trigram
    FROM recurse1
    WHERE (LEN(processedfield1) - 3) >= Position
),

recurse2 AS (
    SELECT 
        field2,
        processedfield2,
        1 AS Position,
        SUBSTRING(processedfield2, 1, 3) AS Trigram
    FROM preprocessCTE2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        field2,
        processedfield2,
        Position + 1 AS Position,
        SUBSTRING(processedfield2, Position + 1, 3) AS Trigram
    FROM recurse2
    WHERE (LEN(processedfield2) - 3) >= Position
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    recurse1.field1,
    recurse2.field2
FROM 
    recurse1 INNER JOIN
    recurse2 ON
    recurse1.Trigram = recurse2.Trigram
```

Comment: Trigrams with spaces should be ignored.